# "that was a classic money handshake"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I'm reading the play "Dumb Show" by Joe Penhall. [(See on Google Books)](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ZHlGLoiy5yAC&lpg=PA5&dq=Dumb%20Show%20Joe%20Penhall%20money%20handshake&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q=Dumb%20Show%20Joe%20Penhall%20money%20handshake&f=false)

Almost at the beginning of the play one of the characters uses this phrase: *classic money handshake*. What does it mean?

```
(Barry and Greg shake hands). 

Barry: Hello. You're not a mason. There was nothing funny about your hand shake.
       That was the classic chop from the top. That was a classic money handshake.
      (does it).
      'I'm going to dominate you and take all your money'. And this is a
      showbiz handshake.
```

What does *the classic chop from the top* mean?

Comment: A handshake where there is some form of money exchanged, either by bribing, deception or forcefully taking, etc. I don't suppose there's any good form of money exchange involved here.

Comment: Might be related to "money shot", which apparently has a number of derivatives like "money quote", "money players", "money position": [“Money quote”: Phrase Origin, metaphors involved?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53681)

Comment: silver and golden handshakes?